# Find roots of $\sin(a\,x)\sin(b\,y)-r\,\sin(b\,x)\sin(a\,y)$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Given $a,b,r$, I would like to find the roots of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^2$:

$$f(x,y)=\sin(a\,x)\sin(b\,y)-r\,\sin(b\,x)\sin(a\,y)$$

As you can see below, the roots of $f$ are curves (in red), parametrized by $x$ and $y$ (for arbitrary $a,b,r$).

[image]

Can I find the equations of the red curves?

Numerically, a possibility is to find an approximate root $(x_0,y_0)$, then numerically identify $\delta$ such that $f(x_0+\varepsilon,y_0+\delta)=o(\varepsilon^{p+1})$ for a given $\varepsilon$, using a Taylor expansion of order $p$. I am wondering if there would be a more elegant solution, and possibly closed-form.

Comment: Are $a,b$ assumed to be positive integers? (asked since your graph seems to be periodic)

Comment: @coffeemath: positive reals, but they are not integers. It's just an illusion I guess.

Comment: If you have an approximate root of the solution, I guess that Newton-Raphson would be a good way without worrying about Taylor expansions.